# How do I replace text in all files containing specific text on Linux?

Tags: bash, replace

With this command I am able to find all files in a directory containing a specific text:

```
grep -rnw '/path/mypath' -e 'mypattern'
```

Now, I'd like to replace all the occurencies of 'mypattern' in 'mypattern2' in all matching files.

Is there a command in Linux that combined with this one also replace the text in all files?

Comment: Yes, to name a few, `sed` , `awk` , `perl` the unx editors, `ed` and `ex` , combined with a shell `for loop` or `find`

Comment: Even `vim` has `argdo` for that matter.

Comment: You may take advantage from [Find and replace words in text file recursively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269279/) and [How can I replace a string in a file(s)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a command in Linux that replaces the text in all files. Try:

```
find "/path/mypath" -type f -exec sed -i "s/mypattern/mypattern2/g" {} \;
```

as U880D proposes. No need to fetch first the matching files with `grep`, `sed` is able to search and to replace.